# apache service not started xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I am using `Apache 2.2.17` with `XAMPP Control Version 2.5` but and apache is using port 8080 but when I start apache service it shows:

```
ERROR : Apache service not started [-1]
```

and to see the port is used by any other program i did

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

from where i got `PID 2952` is using that port which is `java.exe` as I need that to run my program. 
I had changed port in the `apache/conf/httpd.conf` file as

```
#Listen 0.0.0.0:87
#Listen [::]:87
Listen 87
```

and `ServerName localhost:87` and restarted my pc but the port was not changed .Please help to get access to `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Look in the apache error log for startup errors.

Comment: where can i get apache error logs?

Answer (score 1):

Take care of a few things.

Firstly, close Xampp completely before editing the `httpd.conf` file. Xampp tends to run Apache and other stuffs in the background even after you quit it. To check if it's closed completely, use the Task Manager.

Secondly, try any other Port number. To check which ports are unused, open command prompt and type `netstat -an`. You can view the list of ports that are open.